# Send another message if are more than 25 field Discord NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am making a discord bot [(Here is the original one)](https://github.com/ThatZiv/FiveM-Bot) in javascript of my GTA V RP server, the bot has a command that tells you the name, id and ping of the players but when there are more than 25 players an error occurs ( RangeError: RichEmbeds may not exceed 25 fields.). I have thought about the idea of ​​having more than 25 players send the others in another message.

Here´s the code:

````
exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

  var util = require("../fivem");
  message.delete();
  if (servers[message.guild.id].guild === message.guild.id) {
    try {
      var arg = `${servers[message.guild.id].ip}`
      /*    var args = `${servers[message.guild.id].ip}` */
      let api = `http://${arg}/players.json`
      let api2 = `http://${arg}/info.json`
      /*    if (!args) {return util.embed("Please Specify a Direct-IP address ex: `"+config.prefix+"players thatziv.ddns.net:30120`")}
         if (!message.content.includes(":")) {return util.embed("Please Specify a port ex: **"+config.prefix+"players thatziv.ddns.net__:30120__**")} */
      req(api2, function (err, response, main) {
        req(api, function (err, response, body) {
          if (err) {
            util.zembed("That server is offline or does not exist... \n**Console:**\n```js\n" + err + "```")
          }
          else {
            try {
              var start = JSON.parse(body)
              var start2 = JSON.parse(main)

              if (start == null || start == []) {
                var e = 0
              } else {
                var e = start.length;
              }
              var embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
                .setColor(color)
                .setAuthor(state, icon)
                .setThumbnail(icon)
                .setDescription(`__**FamousLifeRP Players**__\n(First 25 players)\n**${e}** out of **${start2.vars.sv_maxClients}** Players.`)
              start.forEach(function (element) {
                var sv = `**${element.name}**\nID: **${element.id}** Ping: **${element.ping}**`;

                embed.addField(`**${element.name}**`, `ID: **${element.id}** Ping: **${element.ping}**`)
              })

              message.channel.send({ embed: embed });
              log(`Used Command [PLAYERS] in ${message.guild.name}`)
        
            } catch (err) {
              util.embed("That server is offline or does not exist...\n**Console:**\n```js\n" + err + "```")
            }
          }

        })

      })

    } catch (err) {
      util.embed("That server does not exist. \n**Console:**\n```js\n" + err + "```");
    }
  } else {
    return util.embed("Please **set** a Direct-Address for this server. ex: `" + config.prefix + "set thatziv.ddns.net:30120`\n***__Please make sure to include the address with port.__***")

  }
};



var exampleJSON = [
  {
    "endpoint": "[::ffff:5.15.226.104]:27594",
    "id": 294,
    "identifiers": [
      "steam:110000114ff0dc9",
      "license:12eaf8ef61955729188ff56b08e820c8a61bcbc3",
      "ip:5.15.226.104"
    ],
    "name": "Leonadro Di la Londra",
    "ping": 165
  }
]
````

And here´s the error:

[image: Error]

"That server is offline or does not exist...
Console:
RangeError: RichEmbeds may not exceed 25 fields."

Comment: `I have thought about the idea of ​​having more than 25 players send the others in another message.` - Have you thought about trying to code this too?

Answer (score 0):

create an array of embeds, loop through your array. Use a counter inside the loop. Add fields to the embed as normal. Once counter hits 25, push a new embed object into the array of embeds, then redirect your new fields to the newly added embed. Repeat until you finish adding all fields. Then you can send all of the embeds to the channel.
(might wanna watch out for message ratelimit if you have a ton of data)

I'm not going to write all the code for you but it should look something like this:

```js
const embeds = [];
let counter = 0;
start.forEach(e => {
   if(!embeds[Math.floor(counter/25)]) { //checks if the embed exists in array
      embeds.push(new Discord.MessageEmbed(); 
      //add embed, do whatever you need to title, etc. here
   }
   embeds[Math.floor(counter/25)].addField("",""); // whatever you need to add
   counter++;
}
embeds.forEach(e => {
   message.channel.send(e);
   //might watch out for this too because they dont send synchronously 
   //you could try Promise.all or something
}
```

Another thing to note is that your code snippet seems to be using a deprecated version of Discord.js, please use the latest version (12.5.1)

Comment: @TheRedyYT sorry bud, this is a help forum, not a "pls write my entire code for me" forum